# Change bundle product's price after add to cart

Tags: cart, price, bundled-product

How can I change the price of a bundle product after it's added to the cart? Doesn’t matter if product type is fixed or dynamic, but its final price needs to change.

Answer (score 3):

You can set custom prices with an observer on `catalog_product_get_final_price` with code like this:

```
$observer->getProduct()->setFinalPrice(...);
```

But for bundles it is not that easy, at least with dynamic pricing, because **the bundle itself does not have a price**. Technically it's just a container for other products and its price is the sum of the child prices. The aforementioned event is triggered for each of the simple products in `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getSelectionFinalTotalPrice()`, so you'd need to adjust each of those so that the sum is as you want it to.

Comment: How can I change bundle item's price on addtocart. It means suppose, I select one bundle item "keyboard" with 100$ but after add to cart its need to change price with 50$. Then how it can be done ? please note : keyboard is not a main bundle product,but bundle item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Magento event-observer facility,`sales_quote_add_item` to change the product after add to cart. I am not sure about How this one work with bundle product but for simple product it works clearly.

config.xml

```
<events>
<sales_quote_add_item>
<observers>
<namespace_modulename>
<type>singleton</type>
<class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
<method>setProductPrice</method>
</namespace_modulename>
</observers>
</sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

Namespace/Modulename/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php   
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function setProductPrice($observer)
    {
       //code to change your product price
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change price when product is added to cart from backend. Other thing, I had overwrite function name updateQuoteItems() of model 'Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create'.  Here I add code like : $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price); .   This will work in all product types except bundle product. Please help me .

Comment: Your class does not need to extend `Varien_Event_Observer`.  That is the class that is passed as an argument to each method, (the `$observer` argument in your code above). The Observer class does not need to extend anything in order to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in config.xml

```
<config>
.
.
.
<global>
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <namespace_modulename_change_price>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
                </namespace_modulename_change_price>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

and in your observer.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter($observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }
    $custom_price = 100; //set your custom price

    //getting price from catalog model
    $productPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getFinalPrice();

    //adding custom with original price
    $finalPrice = (int)$custom_price + (int)$productPrice;

    if($finalPrice > 0){
        $item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($finalPrice); 

}
```

I haven't tested, but should work.

Comment: its not working with bundle product :(